# Looking for a custom solution to copy data from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to simplify a process for field employees at my work. The baseline case is that the employees fill out Daily Detail Reports in a single Excel Workbook throughout the year with the hours they have worked that day, the project # and Phase Code their labor costs will hit and the hours that they worked that day on that particular project. It is very common for the same project number and phase code to be used more than once for a single day (i.e. multiple row entries which will need the total hours added together based on the condition of having the same project number and phase code for that day). See attached "Detail Report WB" image.

Our employees then have to enter the same data in a different format (i.e. only one line allowed per project number and phase code pair per day) in a separate workbook. See attached "Timesheet Import WB" image. The timesheet workbook is driven based on the week end date for that week (i.e. Sunday). The Daily Detail Report workbook however, is driven based on the week beginning date and Sundays are not included in the Daily Detail Report. To make things more complicated, the dates listed in the Daily Detail report are based on formulas and do not house the actual date value in the cells.

The goal of this solution is to take the information entered into the Daily Detail Report workbook and place it into the Timesheet workbook via a sub function based on a ActiveX command button click event. See the attached “End Goal” image.

So far I have compiled the following code to allow the user to click the import button which prompts the user to find the Daily Detail Report workbook that they would like to import data from. This code also allows for the user to input the week end date desired for the Timesheet workbook. I was trying to use the week end date to find the desired data in the Daily Detail Report workbook, but this is proving difficult. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. It’s been years since I took into to computer programming in VBA back in college.

Images are located here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7BjXxM59FFyQlM5eThvc0dDWUU?usp=sharing

Thanks!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Define All Variables
Dim GCell As Range
Dim fDialog As FileDialog, result As Integer
Dim MyDetailReport As String
Dim MyTimeSheet As String
Dim MySheet As String
Dim ProjNum As String
Dim PhaseCode As String
Dim Hours As String
Dim WkEndDate As String

'Find source file
Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    fDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    fDialog.Title = "Select Daily Report File to Import"
    fDialog.InitialFileName = "W:\PDX - Mechanical Construction\Operations\Detailing\Daily Tracking Logs\"
    fDialog.Filters.Clear
    fDialog.Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xlsx"
    If fDialog.Show = -1 Then
        MyDetailReport = fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If

'Enter date to look for in workbook
  WkEndDate = InputBox("Insert Week End Date in format mm/dd/yyyy", "User date", Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy"))
  If IsDate(WkEndDate) Then
    WkEndDate = Format(CDate(WkEndDate), "mm/dd/yyyy")
    'Place Week End Date into Timesheet workbook
    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AE5")
        .Value = WkEndDate
    End With
  Else
    MsgBox "Wrong date format"
  End If

'Use the current sheet to store found data
MySheet = ActiveSheet.Name

'Use Error Handling routine in case of errors
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'Turn off screen updating to run macro faster
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyDetailReport & MyTimeSheet

'Search Detail Report "Daily Report Log" sheet for the selected Week End Date
Set GCell = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(WkEndDate, LookIn:=xlValues)
GCell = GCell.Offset(2, 1)
    If GCell.Value = "" Then
        GCell = GCell.Offset(1, 0)
    Else
        'copy data formulas to correct format for Timesheet workbook
    End If

'Error Handling
ErrorHandler:
Select Case Err.Number

        'Common error #2: the specified data wasn't in the target workbook.
        Case 9, 91
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            MsgBox "The value " & WkEndDate & " was not found."
            Exit Sub
        'General case: turn screenupdating back on, and exit.
        Case Else
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Exit Sub
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: "This is proving difficult". What, exactly, are the problems you are running into? What specific question do you have that would be aided with a specific answer? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Now that I've stepped away from this for awhile, I've been thinking that I could form a solution through pivot tables or some very complicated sumifs functions. Is there a way to generate a pivot table in vba? Or a way to lookup multiple sumif ranges similar to the excel SUMIFS() function?

Comment: "pivot table VBA" on the web will show lots of hits, including MSFT documentation.